# Abrir uma página antes de carregar o header

Tags: php, javascript

**A questão é, estou tentando abrir uma página antes que o `header` da página principal seja executado;**

```
<?php
   
echo("<script language=\"javascript\">");
echo("window.open('teste.php', '_blank');");
echo("</script>");
header("Location: http://www.google.com");

?>
```

Já tentei dessa forma, porém quando a página abre ela já vai direto no `header`(redirecionando pra página do google e ignorando a abertura da "teste.php").

Já tentei por um `sleep` antes do `header`, mas aparentemente também não faz muito sentido na execução. Por que ele simplesmente continua ignorando e indo direto ao `header`.

**Alguma alternativa?**

*Obs.: A página "teste.php" tem que necessariamente abrir em uma nova aba, sem que seja um popup ou algo similar, com o `target = _blank` como no pequeno código que deixei*

Comment: Estranho isso, deveria abrir teste.php em nova aba e gerar um erro Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui fazer por PHP. Mas uma alternativa seria usar Javascript tanto para abrir a pop-up como para fazer o redirect:

```
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('https://www.example.com');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'https://www.google.com';</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estranho isso `vai direto no header` , deveria abrir teste.php em nova aba e gerar um erro Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by .....

Você pode abrir as duas paginas no mesmo script, uma `_blank` e outra `_self`

```
echo("<script language=\"javascript\">");
echo("window.open('teste.php', '_blank');");
echo("window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');");
echo("</script>");
```

Outra forma é usar meta refresh

```
<?php

echo("<script language=\"javascript\">");
echo("window.open('teste.php', '_blank');");
echo("</script>");

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='http://www.google.com'\" />";

?>
```